# Enable core dump on Linux 2.6.35

Tags: linux-kernel, core-dump

I'm running kernel 2.6.35 on a custom embedded device (ARMv7). I'm trying to get a core dump but it appears core dumps are disabled.

My kernel config can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/XXZ8YyaA

My test application is the following:

```
int main() {
    return 1/0;
}
```

I expect the following:

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

But instead get this:

```
Floating point exception
```

Meaning core dumps are disabled. How can I enable them for my platform? It looks like the option to toggle functionality in the kernel `CONFIG_COREDUMP`  wasn't added till kernel [version 3.7](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=046d662f481830e652ac34cd112249adde16452a). Is it not always enabled in previous kernels?

```
# ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         unlimited
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       1710
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 1710
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
# ./crash
Floating point exception
```

Comment: Is the core dump file size set to zero? Test with `ulimit -c`. Change it to unlimited with `ulimit -c unlimited`.

Comment: There are know bugs in those kernel versions that make the kernel/any server using it hang once in a while. Hope you are trying to debug such a situation.

Comment: @Kusalananda Doesn't matter if `ulimit -c` is set to `0` or `unlimited`, core dumps are disabled. It should still report a core dump regardless if it creates the file or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing kernel option was `CONFIG_ELF_CORE`.

`General setup -> Configure standard kernel features (for small systems) -> Enable ELF core dumps`

After enabling this I'm able to get core dumps.

```
# ./crash
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```